# how to display grid graph using boost?

Tags: c++, boost, graph

I want like to print the grid graph like this.

[image]

I tried the following code

```
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/grid_graph.hpp>
typedef boost::grid_graph<2> Grid;
int main()
{
    boost::array<std::size_t, 2> lengths = { { 3, 5 } };
    Grid grid(lengths);
    std::ofstream gout;
    gout.open("test.dot");
    boost::write_graphviz(gout, grid);

}
```

and got output like this.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'd be happy with replacing `dot` with `neato` there:

http://www.graphviz.org/category/graphviz-terms/neato

[image]

Comment: I'd use the library functions (sadly the documentation site seems unresponsive). Or just... `system('neato -Tpng -Goverlap=false test.dot > test.png');` then? Beware of security vulnerabilities if you compose the command from dynamic data. Beware of error handling. Good luck

Comment: How nice of you to tell me then, and why don't you post a new question showing what you do and where you're stuck?

Comment: @angel that really doesn't make any sense. Please consider posting a new question if you have other problems. None of this is related to your question  here.

Answer (score 1):

I learned how to plot rectangular shape from sehe's answer above. But `neato` always gives me a tilted graph. To force the graph to align its row in horizontal direction, we can set `pos` [attribute](https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:pos) of grah nodes. I use custom property writer to do it. Here is my implementation.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/graph/grid_graph.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>

struct PosWriter
{
  template <typename Vertex>
  void operator()(std::ostream& out, const Vertex& v)
  {
    out << "[pos=\"" << v[0] << "," << v[1] << "\"]";
  }
};

int main()
{
  using Graph = boost::grid_graph<2>;
  boost::array<std::size_t, 2> lengths = {5, 3};
  Graph g(lengths);
  std::ofstream file("grid.dot");
  boost::write_graphviz(file, g, PosWriter());

  return 0;
}
```

Now the graph ploted looks similar to what BGL documentation shows.

[image]

Comment: Don't know how I missed this. This is actually quite instructive. Nice example code. Thanks