# How to use graphviz neato from within C++ program

Tags: c++, boost

[Contination of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37608482/how-to-display-grid-graph-using-boost)

```
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/grid_graph.hpp>
typedef boost::grid_graph<2> Grid;
int main()
{
    boost::array<std::size_t, 2> lengths = { { 3, 5 } };
    Grid grid(lengths);
    std::ofstream gout;
    gout.open("test.dot");
    boost::write_graphviz(gout, grid);

}
```

I run

```
system('neato -Tpng overlap=false test.dot > test.png');
```

from a c++ program. It is not working.i.e png file is not created

When I run the same command from a console prompt, it does work as expected.

Comment: can you show a code snippet, or the error you receive?

Comment: On POSIX systems (like Linux and OSX) the `system` function invokes the shell to run your command, so redirection should work just fine. Can you please elaborate, and if possible try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: will not get any error .but test.png is not created.simply display the dot file

Comment: @JoachimPileborg png file is not created

Comment: which OS are you using? Can you provide a sample dot file and the 6-lines code that is fully compilable and runs the system command? Then all we have to do to test is run that code with the dot file in the folder.

Comment: @coyotte508 ubuntu

Comment: @angel what do you mean "simply display the dot file", is it a result of the code before or the `system` call? Please do add the whole code in this question as well, not just  say "click this link and add this line".

Comment: @angel please refrain from comment spamming. If people are interested they will watch this space, trust me.

Answer (score 4):

If redirection doesn't work on your system's shell, use the option:

```
system("neato -Tpng overlap=false test.dot -o test.png");
```

Also be aware of your working directory. Make sure your input is in the current working directory, and also check that you are looking for the output (`test.png`) in that same directory.

Alternatively, spell out the paths

```
system("neato -Tpng overlap=false /path/to/dir/test.dot -o /path/to/dir/test.png");
```

> CAVEAT: of course, in C++ strings backslashes need to be escaped, if your paths contains them

Comment: Come on, @angel You can do better than dismissing things in seconds. Also, if you want to say "Hey I tried it, but it doesn't seem to work for me", do so. Your "victim" attitude "not working..." just makes you look like lazy and whining.

Comment: Using my psychic debugging skills, I added another hint. (It might not apply, but we can't tell since your question doesn't say anything about how and where you run your program).

Comment: I guess that's what I was saying when I said "You can do better than dismissing things in seconds". There was no real reason why you couldn't "observe" the png being saved earlier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113729/discussion-between-sehe-and-angel).

Comment: The question is completely unrelated and has nothing to with boost, graphs, graphviz, dot files or C++. It's just a C/POSIX standard library function.